# Allow non-admin user to sudo without access to admin account data

Tags: permission, user-account

I need to lend my MBP to a friend for a few days while their laptop is out for repair. I would like to not have to erase my account to do that.

I have set up another User Account for them without Administrator Privileges.

They need to use my laptop for development and will probably require `sudo` access at some point.

---

Is there a way for me to allow them `sudo` access but not allow them access to any data stored for my own user.

Anecdotally, this does not sound possible, because `sudo` access would mean the highest access on the machine so everything will be accessible.

Is there any other way to achieve this without having to erase my data?

<sub>I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1334807/is-it-possible-to-separately-encrypt-individual-user-home-folders-in-macos) that is looking for ways to encrypt each user folder separately but without answers.</sub>

Comment: **Assuming the internal drive is not encrypted and one has physical access to your computer, all one needs to do to access your data is to boot the computer to the Recovery HD or from a Linux Live OS USB Drive, even a macOS USB Installer, and they have access to your data regardless of how you edit the `sudoers` file!!!**

Comment: Regardless of any merit the (current) accepted answer might have, and it does have some but IMO not really in this case, because once you physically hand your computer over, there are a number of vectors your data can be easily accessed and copied off the computer and done right, you'll have no way of knowing it was even done! _Cont'd..._

Comment: _Cont'd.._, The simplest of which is to boot to the Recovery HD where it can be simply and easily copied to a USB drive formatted as FAT32 where effectively the permissions are no longer observed. The e.g. Macintosh HD can be unmounted and remounted read-only and thus there will be no access time modifications to assuage any doubt that curiosity didn't get the best of your friend. FWIW I have never and will never hand over to anyone any computer that has my data on it! Never have to worry or give it a second though in doing so!

Comment: Thank you for the insight @user3439894. I understand that physically handing over a computer to someone without an encrypted disk means all my data is just waiting for the user to exploit. And for a scenario of that sort, I would agree that there is no solution but to delete or encrypt all data. But given the current scenario, I know the person as a friend and there is a factor of trust baked into the exchange. I am not assuming any intent on his part to misbehave. I just want to not make this very easy if the thought strikes him at all.

Comment: The accepted answer will not work for all scenarios, but in this situation, that was the extent of my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The Answer:

Yes, it's definitely possible. `sudo` is designed to implement *fine-grained* security policies. As an [example of *fine-grained*](https://superuser.com/questions/167631/fine-grained-sudoers-configuration-allowed-commandline-arguments), `sudo` can be configured to allow a user to run a particular command, but exclude certain options for the command. [Don't get `sudo` confused with `su`](https://kb.iu.edu/d/amyi).

And so, when you say, ***"sudo access would mean the highest access on the machine so everything will be accessible"***, that's simply ***not true***. IMHO, `sudo` was made to order for the exact problem you are faced with: "How do I give a user access to resources he needs to do his job, *without* giving him the run of the castle?" You may also appreciate the fact that `sudo` performs extensive *logging* of all `sudo` usage. This provides *accountability* for all `sudo` users because, unlike `su`, users execute `sudo` from *their* account, not the `root` account.

Here are two examples to illustrate this point. These are two entries that would go in the `sudoers` file - the file that defines a user's privileges under `sudo`. In the first example, the user `friend` will be given "access to everything"; i.e. unlimited `root` privileges:

#### Example: `sudo` for Full `root` Privileges

```
friend   ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

In the next example, the user `friend` will only be given privileges to run the software update option (`-U`) on the utility [`youtube-dl`](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/index.html). This specification will confer `root` privileges to run **only** this one command with this one option (although in this case most of the other options do not require `root` privileges.):

#### Example: `sudo` for Limited `root` Privileges

```
friend   ALL = (ALL) /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -U
```

### A Brief Overview of `sudo`:

I can't explain `sudo` in the space of this answer. As you'll see that simply is not possible. Instead, I'll try to provide provide a "*walking tour*" with some references that will give you a better understanding of what `sudo` can (and can't) do, and how to **configure** `sudo` to implement the security policy you want.

- [Todd Miller](https://www.sudo.ws/todd/todd.html) currently maintains `sudo` as he has [since 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo#History). That probably makes him the ***godfather of `sudo`***.
- There is a [prodigious amount of documentation on `sudo`](https://www.sudo.ws/), including many older versions - including [ver. `1.8.17p1`](https://www.sudo.ws/man.html) used in the current version of macos (Mojave, 10.14.5).
- Perhaps a good place to begin learning about `sudo` is [in a nutshell](https://www.sudo.ws/intro.html)
- Having read this nutshell overview, you now know that `sudo` is *typically* configured using the `sudoers` file. This is where you will create the specifications that implement your security policy; the specifications that define what resources your friend can access while using your machine.
- Again, there's a lot of documentation. You'll want to read `man sudo` ([ver 1.8.17 online](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudo.man.html)), and `man sudoers` ([ver 1.8.17 online](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.17/sudoers.man.html)). **OK, skim through it at least, and study the EXAMPLES** :) And BTW, your friend will need to read `man sudo` also, as he'll be using it!
- Once you've decided what resources your friend needs, you can prepare to tackle actually editing/creating your own `sudoers` file. But there are some things you should know first:

  1. The `sudoers` file should only be edited with `visudo`. To access it, you'll need to be logged in as (or `su` to) the "admin" user on your Mac. Upon entering the command shown below, the **Sample** sudoers file will be opened in your admin user's default editor (I've set mine to `nano`).
  2. Know that editing the `sudoers` file carries risks. Minimze those risks by **NEVER** editing `sudoers` except through the `visudo` app. `visudo` is designed to validate the syntax of the `sudoers` file when it is saved. That won't save you from errors that have the correct syntax of course, but it's far less likely that you'll leave your machine in an unusable state!

### Making changes to the `sudoers` file:

**And so:** To edit the `sudoers` file, login as (or `su` to) the admin user, open a terminal window, and enter:

```bsh
bash-3.2$ sudo visudo
Password:                # you'll need to enter your admin user's password here
```

The editor specified in your `environment` will open, and the `sudoers` file will be listed. The `User specifications` section is near the end of the file; you can insert one of the example lines from above, taking care not to edit either of the existing lines:

> root            ALL = (ALL) ALL
>   %admin          ALL = (ALL) ALL
>   # insert your additions below here; e.g.:
>   friend   ALL = (ALL) /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -U

When you finish your edits, write the modified file, then exit the editor. `visudo` will automatically check the syntax of your `sudoers` file, and alert you if it finds a problem. You should never override these alerts; find and fix the issue, or simply comment out your changes until you do.

### Using `sudoedit` to limit access to files

**One final example:** You wanted to grant `sudo` access, but not allow access to any data stored for your user. For purposes of this example I'll assume that you want to give your friend the ability to edit the file `/etc/fstab.hd` (a *do-nothing* file), and *all* files in the directory `/etc/ssh`.

You can use the `sudoedit` specification in the `sudoers` file to grant your friend access to files or entire directories that you specify. Here's how to accomplish that:

1. Run `sudo visudo` to open the `sudoers` file for editing.
2. As previously, enter the following `sudoedit` lines just below those you added previously; i.e.

> root            ALL = (ALL) ALL
>   %admin          ALL = (ALL) ALL
>   # insert your additions below here; e.g.:
>   friend   ALL = (ALL) /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -U
>   # insert sudoedit specs below here:
>   friend          ALL = (root) sudoedit /etc/ssh/*
>   friend          ALL = (root) sudoedit /etc/fstab.hd

To edit these files, your friend will enter the following command(s) in a terminal window:

```bsh
MyMacBook:~ friend$ sudo -e /etc/fstab.hd  

# or...

MyMacBook:~ friend$ sudo -e /etc/ssh/ssh_config

# which will open the specified file in `friend's` specified editor
```

### Limits of `sudo`

You should also keep in mind that `sudo` has its limits.

First and foremost, `sudo` is used to get  `root` privileges for a user from the command line (Terminal). It has no role in determining privileges anywhere else in the system; e.g. to add a new user in `System Preferences`. Outside the shell then, the *authorization database* controls access privileges, and `sudo` has no relevance. You may need a [tool like this](https://www.dssw.co.uk/authbuddy/) to manipulate the authorization database. **{02/29/20 Edit:** `authbuddy` is no longer maintained; its author suggests Apple's `security` tool instead. See `man security` from the CLI, or [this html version](https://www.dssw.co.uk/reference/security.html) **}**

Secondly, `sudo` should NOT be considered as a tool to harden the system against malicious users. Rather, it's simply a tool for reducing risk and increasing accountability for *authorized* users. That's not to say it "rolls over", it's only to say that its purpose is not system hardening.

This seems like a good point to stop, and catch our breath :) Your question did not include any specific security goals or policies, so it doesn't seem to make sense to prattle on with more examples (and there are plenty of those available for the cost of a Google search). However, if you do want help with specific configurations, you can either edit your question here, or post a new question. And don't forget that as `sudo` is available on virtually all *nix platforms, there are other SE sites that may prove useful: [SuperUser SE](https://superuser.com/) and [Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) are two examples.

---

Other potentially useful resources related to `sudo`:

1. [AppleGazette on editing the `sudoers` file](https://www.applegazette.com/mac/pro-terminal-commands-how-and-why-to-edit-sudoers-on-macos/)
2. [AP Lawrence on *Using `sudo`*](https://aplawrence.com/Basics/sudo.html)
3. [Using `sudoedit` to limit file editing to a specific directory/ies](https://serverfault.com/a/206836/515728)
4. [More on `sudoedit` (aka `sudo -e`, aka `sudo --edit`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22084506/5395338)
5. [What's So Great About `sudoedit`?](http://www.wingtiplabs.com/blog/posts/2013/03/13/sudoedit/)
6. [Good general (not Mac-specific) help from from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos)
7. [The `sudo` command, Part 2 of a 4-part series on "*Demystifying root*"](https://scriptingosx.com/2018/04/demystifying-root-on-macos-part-2-the-sudo-command/)

Comment: Might be important to add that this only works if all the required commands are known before handing over the Mac to somebody else, and if none of the these commands allows the user to spawn a new shell.

Comment: @nohillside: It's not necessary to know all of the commands beforehand; the commands can be enabled by location rather than individually (e.g. `/usr/bin`). And the issue with spawning a new shell has (I think) been addressed with the `NOEXEC` option that was introduced some time ago. For example: `username  ALL = NOEXEC: /usr/bin/less`; [ref](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos). `sudo` is [not perfect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421021/286615); but it's certainly a lot more capable than giving "blanket" `root` priviliges.

Comment: **Assuming the internal drive is not encrypted and one has physical access to your computer, all one needs to do to access your data is to boot the computer to the Recovery HD or from a Linux Live OS USB Drive, even a macOS USB Installer, and they have access to your data regardless of how you edit the `sudoers` file!!!**

Comment: @user3439894: And your point is...?

Comment: What in my first comment did you not understand?

Comment: @user3439894: I understood all of it. Did you not understand the OP's original question? He asked about `sudo`, and used the word ***friend***. And if you're referring to my typo, `Secondly...`, it would have been much more efficient to have just pointed that out, eh?

Comment: I am not talking about any typos there may be in your answer. The bottom line is the OP is worried about his friend accessing his data and as such, with the assumption that nothing is encrypted, it is absolutely totally irrelevant how one edits the `sudoers` file because once the computer is physically handed over his data can be accessed!

Comment: @user3439894: I guess then that the difference between you and I is that I'll assume the OP knows his friend, and has a general idea of sudo's limitations, whereas you seem to assume he knows neither. I think you've made your point, so perhaps give it a rest now?

Comment: The only assumption I am making is if the drive is not encrypted, and as such it's irrelevant how well he knows his friend or how much he trust his friend, his data is vulnerable once the computer is handed over! As to giving it a rest, well you're the one who pursued the line of inquiry after my first comment!

Comment: @user3439894: Indeed, and thank you for pointing that out. As far as pursuing a line of inquiry with you, all I can say is that I won't repeat that mistake.

Comment: @user3439894: Apologies, but I can't resist ( the temptation was just too great) informing you of a [great opportunity to weigh in on this answer also.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360359/149366)

Comment: @Seamus that is a totally different question - that one asks if the other party can be trusted. This question is that the other party cannot be trusted and so how do you block their access to the data and the answer is that as they have physical access to the hardware you cannot. Your explanation of sudo is very good but implementing your plan will not stop the friend from accessing the owner's data.

Comment: @Mark: It's different, I'll concede that. But I can't concede that this question implies the other party (who the OP identifies as a ***friend***) cannot be trusted; your comment boils down to conjecture and personal opinion. And I never said (except in the typo I corrected) that `sudo` would prevent malicious mischief!! How do you conjur that conclusion? The relevant facts are these: 1. OP asked about `sudo`; 2) `sudo` is widely used for parceling privileges. End Of.

Comment: The title asks for sudo but the question says ... but not allow them access to any data stored for my own user. So the question asks how to stop the friend reading data. (The OP has done a bit of looking and thinks that sudo might be the answer but that is a red herring)m If the friend can get access as we know - what does the sudo option add to security - just let him use the compute and ask him not to look at data is the same security,

Comment: @Mark: No, it's not the same security. Again, operative words in the OP's question are: **friend**, `sudo` in the title, and the requirement :`... will probably require sudo access`. So I told him how to do that, and *you* want to argue. Fine, argue. Sheesh - are you a professional second-guesser, or is it just a hobby?

Comment: I will clear the air around this. This is specifically for a friend, and I do not assume any malicious intent. I just feel curiosity can sometimes get the better of people and would just like to make it difficult for my friend to act on a moment of curiosity. Thank you for such a detailed answer, time to get down to understanding all of it.

Comment: @Sinstein: Thanks for weighing in. Let us know if any further questions come up.

Answer (score -1):

Once somebody has `sudo` rights they can access basically any non-encrypted files of other users easily. They can even copy encrypted files and use whatever tool they can get their hands on to crack the encryption. Also, with a lot of important stuff stored within `~/Library` it might not be enough to just move `Documents` to an encrypted DMG.

So from the top of my head I see two options:

- Log in as administrator and create an encrypted volume with the content of `/Users/your-main-user`, then remove the unencrypted folder content. Beside the caveat above it might be easier to just backup everything and delete the user
- Set up remote access, ensure that you can run `sudo` if accessing through `ssh` and then have your friend ping you whenever they need to run `sudo`

PS: There might also be some (not totally safe) ways to restrict `sudo` to certain commands, but for this you need to know these commands upfront.