# Security benefit of using a 'standard' user account?

Tags: security, user-account

As the sole user of my macbook, are there any security benefits of using a standard user account for day-to-day usage and entering in the admin password if needed?

I have found years old, inconclusive, forum arguments, but would be good to hear an updated view.

Thanks!